# C++ Assignment overload self-assignment issue

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I am currently working on an ADT called Text and I'm overloading the assignment operator. When I test the operator like so: `assignText = alpha` everything outputs okay. However, when I do `assignText = assignText` then two solid bars output instead.

assignText is declared as a Text object.

My overloaded assignment operator is as follows:

```
void Text::operator= (const Text& other) { 
bufferSize = other.getLength();
buffer = new char[bufferSize];
buffer = other.buffer; 
}
```

Where `int bufferSize` and `char *buffer`

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If anything else is needed, just let me know.

Comment: Look into the copy-swap idiom.

Comment: Your assignment has likely more problems than that.

Comment: Indeed. The [Rule of Zero](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html) shines when you're allowed to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers already have pointed out various issues with your operator implementation. Here I'll try to understand what's happening for you, i.e. *why* the code behaves as you observe. If `this == &other`, i.e. during self assignment, you take the current length as the size of a new buffer. That new buffer isn't initialized, so at that point it might contain random bytes. The last assignment is a no-op in case of a self-assigment. To sum things up:

```
void Text::operator= (const Text& other) { 
  bufferSize = other.getLength(); // Take length from current object
  buffer = new char[bufferSize];  // Create new buffer, old buffer turns into a memory leak
  buffer = other.buffer;          // No-op as both are the same variable
}
```

So what this tells you is that you end up with a buffer of the current object size but with undefined content. In your case that undefined content happens to represent the vertical bars you mention.

To solve this, make sure to fix the assignment operator based on the suggestions from other answers and comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for the identification and explanation of the issue that I am seeing. That was a very nice breakdown and I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This is a memory leak.  You're assigning two different pointers to `buffer`.

```
 buffer = new char[bufferSize];
 buffer = other.buffer;
```

Comment: While this is true, it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @EdS. With homework-tagged questions, explicit solutions seem to be avoided here.  Is there policy on this?  I don't know offhand.  (On the other hand, there's only so much hinting you can do when debugging a 3 line function)

Comment: For the curious - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: There is [this meta-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/188688) which I tend to take as policy in such situations. Which confirms your point about not providing a ready-to-use full code solution. An explanation about the described effect would be nice nevertheless.

Comment: So by removing the `buffer = new char[bufferSize];` line, I'm removing the memory leak I've created. Also in this way when I now encounter the 3rd line in the self-assignment scenario which is a no-op line, I won't a have a pointer to nothing (which is what is giving me the output of the two solid bars). Is this a correct observation?

Comment: @lemmalemma I think you're heading in the wrong direction.  Calling `new` doesn't create the memory leak.  **losing track of that pointer** creates a memory leak, because you'll never be able to `delete` it.  And that's what happens in the **next** line.  What were you trying to do in that line?

Comment: Well I'm trying to copy over buffer from the other Text object to the Text on the left. I see how having the additional pointer on buffer will cause me to loose track. Will the memory leak still be present with just `bufferSize = other.bufferSize;` and `buffer = other.buffer;`?

Comment: @lemmalemma Your last comment shows the misunderstanding.  You have two lines starting with `buffer =`.  Will a line starting with `buffer =` copy a pointer?  Or copy the contents of the buffer being pointed to?  (What is the type of `buffer`?)  It looks like you want it to do one, then the other.

Comment: Well buffer is a pointer to a character array. So I want to copy the pointer because otherwise I'm a creating a new instance of Text.

Comment: Something where I'm creating a new instance and copying over the member variables is handled by my copy constructor. I don't think that is what this operator overload should aspire to accomplish. Or should it?

Comment: @lemmalemma You're copying a pointer twice.  Your first line copies a pointer to a newly created buffer.  The second line replaces that pointer with a pointer to the other object's buffer.  As if you never wanted that first pointer.  But you did.  This could go into a long discussion about what pointers are and how they work, which isn't healthy for this site.  If you have another specific question, I recommend posting a new question to the site.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience. I will formulate a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding *the problem* at hand, that's covered by the C++ FAQ: [**"Why should I worry about "self assignment"?"**](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/self-assignment-why.html). It's often a good idea to read the FAQ first. Or at least skim it.

When you absolutely have to implement a copy assignment operator, usually the copy-and-swap idiom will be good enough. It's also exception safe. Goes like this:

```
void swapWith( MyType& other ) throw()
{
    // swap them members
}

void operator=( MyType other )
{
    swapWith( other );
}
```

Here the copy constructor creates the formal argument copy, and any exception happens there, so that the copy constructor centralizes also the cleanup in case of copy failure. After that the contents of the two objects are swapped, and the copy object's destructor takes care of cleaning up what was this object's internal stuff. The `void` result type is not yet conventional, but as I see it it's not smart to waste both code and time on supporting expressions with side effects, which are evil.

Now, you **can avoid all this**, simply by using `std::vector` for your buffer.

So that's what I recommend, the really simple solution: use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your assignment operator is fundamentally unsafe. You need to break the old state as the *last* step. Consider

```
Text& Text::operator= (const Text& other) {
    auto new_buffer = new char[other.bufferSize];
    std::copy(other.buffer, other.buffer + other.bufferSize, new_buffer);
    // Now consider whether or not you need to deallocate the old buffer.
    // Then set the new buffer.
    buffer = new_buffer;
    bufferSize = other.bufferSize;
    return *this;
}
```

This ensures that if any problems are encountered, it is guaranteed that the `Text` object is always valid- and as a bonus, is self-assignment-safe. All well-written assignment operators are self-assignment safe.

This is often tied with copy-and-swap, which copies, then swaps- guaranteeing safety.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will work perfectly

```
Text& Text::operator=(const Text& other) 
{ 
    if(this == &other) /* checks for self assignment */
         return *this;

    if(NULL == other.buffer)
         return *this;

    if(NULL != buffer) /* assuming buffer=NULL in constructor */
    {
         delete [] buffer;
         buffer = NULL;
    }

    bufferSize = other.getLength();
    buffer = new char[bufferSize+1];
    memset(buffer, 0, bufferSize+1);
    memcpy(buffer, other.buffer, bufferSize);

    return *this;
}
```

Try this..

Comment: I understand the convention of using Objecttype& and using return *this instead of a void function. Unfortunately, this is a code where we were to construct the source file from the given header file. But I do think checking if other.buffer exists is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought and review, I think I got it. Given that I need to write a void function dictated by the header file that I must construct my implementation from. I took into consideration the comments from Drew Dormann, MvG, as well as others and came up with this:

```
void Text::operator= (const Text &other) 
{ 
    if (this != &other) // takes care of self-assignment
    { 
         delete [] buffer; // delete the old buffer
         bufferSize = other.bufferSize; // assign size variable
         buffer = new char[bufferSize + 1]; // create new buffer
         strcpy(buffer, other.buffer); // copy array
    }
}
```

This works and I believe it is memory leak free.

Comment: `void Text::operator= (const Text &` We should return `*this` from this function so that it supports chaining of multiple assignments like `A = B = C; /* A, B, C are instances of class say Text */` You can try the below code I had written.  Besides you should check whether `other.buffer` is valid, because  if it is invalid then it may produce a segmentation fault.